# Can I set the channel-length of a FinFET to values very much larger than the minimum(or maximum) gate-length provided by the technology node?

Tags: hspice, finfet

I am using 14nm technology node in HSPICE. In the definition of the FinFET, there are two parameters 'lmin=10nm' and 'lmax=30nm'. Does this mean that I cannot set the channel-length to values larger than 30nm?
I have been using 200nm channel length for some research work but now that I have noticed the parameters 'lmin' and 'lmax', I am not sure whether I should continue using 200nm channel length.

Comment: Bump bump, any comments anyone?